# Angular UI-Grid: Clear All Filters with external filtering doesn't refresh rows

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using the external filtering and paging features of angular-ui-grid (v3.0.7) to filter and display my data. When I click on the built-in "Clear All Filters" button the filter text boxes get cleared but the data doesn't refresh, which should take me back to my original data set before it got filtered.

Before I updated to v3.0.7, I had my own custom button to clear the filters which, when clicked, called my own function that called the gridApi.grid.clearAllFilters and then pulled the data again so my data would be back the way it was before it got filtered.

Can I get this built-in "Clear All Filters" button to do somehow do the same thing or can I at least hide this button so that I can add my custom button back?

Comment: You should build a plunker showing the issue in order for other to investigate it easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out my issue. I had changed the code so that the calls to the server wouldn't happen until the user clicked the Enter key, instead of each character they typed. This prevented the Clear All Filters button from doing it's job. I've since removed the logic to check for the Enter key and all's well now.

Comment: What was your solution, exactly?  Did you figure out a way to either hide the `Clear All Filters` button or change the callback of the action?  If so, how?  I'm using external filters and would like to do either one of these.  Thanks.

Comment: Well for my situation we had removed the ability for the filtering to happen as you entered each character. Because of this it wasn't doing what I wanted. We decided to just remove that feature and just have the grid filter the data with each character entered and it worked like the example. Because we went this route we were able to just leave the Clear All Filters button as is.